# How to keep prism application in the system tray?

Tags: mozilla-prism

I need following things:

- Show my application in system tray
- A popup menu on System tray for options like "Exit" or disable "Notifications"
- The application should stay opened in startup even if user restarts her system

Answer (score 1):

1. Prism SHOULD do this, though behavior might be ify, as PRISM was abandoned (as it were), turned into Webrunner, and abandoned again. All more than a year ago.
2. This would only be enabled if Mozilla actually put those features in place prior to ceasing their work on it.
3. Applications cannot stay in 'startup' if the user restarts the system. Can you please clarify?